# How to open a new activity before the Widget load on the screen, Android?

Tags: android

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {...}

@Override
public void onEnabled (Context contex){
    System.out.println("new task flag");
    Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity, ReadName.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    mainActivity.startActivity(i);
}
```

I am trying this code to open a new activity before the widget load on the screen but it is not opening a new activity which i want, the message "new task flag" is comming on the LogCat, but not the activity, what is wrong???
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ReadName is the name of the Activity class that you want to launch, try using this code instead:

```
@Override 
public void onEnabled(Context context){
  Intent i = new Intent(context, ReadName.class);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Also, you can't do system.out.println in android. If you want to print something out, try printing it to the log.

Comment: If the answer doesn't work, you shouldn't accept it. That said, I've edited my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now :D, I appreciate that. u guys are so thankful.